# Database model for user subscriptions

Tags: sql, django

I'm trying to write a simple Django application that a user can post an article and other users can subscribe to articles.  I have most of the database relationships handled but the one i'm struggling with is for topic type, which is a multiple-select form field.

I have a "Topics" table with the various topic types, and when creating the article you can select multiple topics the article relates to, but i only want there to be 1 entry in the "Articles" table.  How would i model this so that when i create an article it's just 1 entry, but i can still relate it to the multiple topics an author might select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), which is Django way to create N-N tables.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Article(models.Model):
    content = ...
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic)
```

In the background, Django will create a new table to link Topic and Article because you can't have a N-N table in SQL.

Comment: Thanks.  It didn't add an additional column to the Article table.  Is it supposed to just use the primary key of Article for the relationship?

Comment: No, you're not supposed to have a list of anything in SQL. As i wrote, in the background, it will create a new table that you won't see to manage the N-N relation. It's only a link table. You can read this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183742/how-do-you-deal-with-m-n-relationships-in-a-relational-database) for more inforamtion.