# Should I use Inner Join in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am working on a student attendance mini-project, and I don't know how to proceed for my database. I'm new to SQL and databases in general so this might seem dumb to you.

So, I want to do a database containing the table student, which contains :  student_id (primary key) , name (string) and attendance(boolean) (that's the bare minimum, i'll add more afterwards) and I want to register the daily attendance of the students. So I want to have all the students tied to every date of the week.

I created a date table in phpMyadmin but I don't know how to proceed to link them, i've tried an Inner Join and it was successful.

The problem is : If i want to add another line to the student table my table won't update, so is there a way to "automatically" tie all the students to the date table ?

Sorry if this seems confused I've tried my best to summarize it !

Comment: Did you try using `FOREIGN KEY` ?

Comment: You don't really need a date table. You need a student table, which stores the id and name of the student, and an attendance table, which stores the id of the student and the date(s) they attended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create relationships in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260441/how-to-create-relationships-in-mysql)

Comment: I've thought about using FOREIGN KEY but I'm not sure if it will tie the dates to my table and more importantly how would the tables stucture will look like

Comment: Have just two tables, firstly a student table with student_id as primary key and secondly a attendance table with student_id as foreign key along with the date field

Comment: How would I do the dates they attended @Strawberry ?

Comment: student_id|attendance_date - alternatively, you store the dates they were absent, if that makes more sense.

Comment: I'm gonna try that and tell you, thanks @MidhunJoy

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. Explain 'add another line to the student table' & '"automatically" tie all the students to the date table'. (Putting words in scare quotes does not make clear the idiosyncratic specific meaning that you didn't write out.)

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & database design.) Dozens of published academic information modeling & database design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. PS *Tables* represent relation(ship)s/associations.  [Foreign keys are not needed to join tables!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842061/3404097) PS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you deal with m..n relationships in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183742/how-do-you-deal-with-m-n-relationships-in-a-relational-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets have some idea about tables should be there to implement a proper Student Attendance system in place. I have copied create script for some of my tables that used for maintaining Students record per course. I hope following sample Table scripts with relation will help you understanding regarding table structure and also to solve your issue.

**Please be noted**, That this table structures for your your reference only. You can add/remove tables/columns as per your requirement once you get an overall idea from this post.

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emal` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `batch` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `batch_staff_idx` (`staff_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `batch_staff` FOREIGN KEY (`staff_id`) REFERENCES `staff` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `batch_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `batch_student_idx` (`batch_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `batch_student` FOREIGN KEY (`batch_id`) REFERENCES `batch` (`batch_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `course_staff_idx` (`staff_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `course_staff` FOREIGN KEY (`staff_id`) REFERENCES `staff` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `attendence` (
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `att_course_idx` (`course_id`),
  KEY `att_student_idx` (`student_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `att_course` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `course` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `att_student` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Your required data will finally store into table Attendance. From this table data, you will be able to find list of students absent/present per date and per course. **Remember**, the attendance table should enrich daily from a automated OR a manual process.